# distribution plot in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, linear-regression

[image]

I need your help in understanding the distribution plot. I was going through tutorial on [this link](http://devarea.com/python-machine-learning-example-linear-regression/#.WxQmilMvxsN). At the end of the post they have mentioned:

> We can see from the graph that most of the times the predictions were correct (difference = 0).

So I am not able to understand how are they analyzing the graph.

Comment: If you are asking about the graph, it's a basic statistical distribution. The x-axis is showing the result of the  `y_test` subtract by `predictions`. The y-axis shows how often the value respective to its x-axis appear in the datasets. If you are asking about the machine learning concept, I am not the best teacher here, but i'm sure that basically the less difference/errors between your `predictions` and your `test_data` is a better machine learning model (assuming we know that it is not an overfitting or underfitting)

Comment: can you give example with respect to the graph. i am still not understanding how is the post saying that the difference is zero. i know i am asking extremely silly question. sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand the discussion in the comment, consider running the following code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.scatter(range(len(y_test)), y_test, marker='d', c='red')
plt.scatter(range(len(predictions)), predictions, marker='d', c='blue')
plt.scatter(range(len(y_test)), (y_test - predictions), marker='^', c='green')
```

It will show you the following plot. The distribution of `y_test` is shown in red diamond. The distribution of `predictions` is shown in blue diamond. If you subtract each point of `y_test` with `predictions`, it results in the green triangle. Since we are trying to predict the tips, we want to minimalize the error between the `test data`, which is the actual data, and the `predictions` we have made with machine learning.

[image: Scatter Distribution]

If you take all those green triangle, and make a `distplot` out of it, it will show you the image you attached to your question. Here are the distributions of each variable:

```
# Code to reproduce the plot below
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

ax = fig.add_subplot(311)
sb.distplot(y_test)
plt.title('y_test')
plt.xlim([-10, 10])

ax = fig.add_subplot(312)
sb.distplot(predictions)
plt.title('predicted tips')
plt.xlim([-10, 10])

ax = fig.add_subplot(313)
sb.distplot(y_test - predictions)
plt.title('y_test - predicted tips')
plt.xlim([-10, 10])

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image: Distplot of each variable]

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the density graph that it shows the relative number of occurrences of the data at given values. The values in question are differences between observed and fitted variable values. If the fit was perfect, all the differences would have been 0, and there would have been just one bar at 0. The fit is not perfect, and there are some differences greater or smaller than 0, but they are not too far from zero.

The conclusion authors draw is probably too strong: the graph does not prove the differences are close to zero, but it suggests the differences are centered around zero. Generally, it is a good result for linear regression.